# Is this an example of casting in Ocaml, unclear on what this line is doing?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir, ocamlyacc

I am looking at a codegen.ml file being used to create LLVM IR. I am unfamilar with Ocaml so just require some clarification

```
  let i32_t      = L.i32_type    context
  and float_t    = L.double_type context

  let ltype_of_typ = function
      A.Int   -> i32_t
    | A.Float -> float_t
  in

  let global_vars : L.llvalue StringMap.t =
    let global_var m (t, n) = 
      let init = match t with
          A.Float -> L.const_float (ltype_of_typ t) 0.0
```

So for this line

```
 A.Float -> L.const_float (ltype_of_typ t) 0.0
```

What is the stuff after "->" doing? Is it casting 0.0 to a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is calling a function `L.const_float` with two parameters. The code reads as if it's setting up a global mapping from names to values. Some of the values appear to be representations of fixed floating numbers. Beyond that I can't help you because I'm not familiar with LLVM.

However there are no "type casts" in OCaml. There are a few functions in the standard library that convert between numeric types (`int_of_float` for example). But there's no language feature for casting types. OCaml is a strongly typed language, and type casting (as in C or C++) is pretty much a violation of that.

It might be more helpful to ask your question in a forum devoted to LLVM.

Comment: Small correction, it is possible to do unsafe type casting in OCaml but it is considered, well, unsafe and to be avoided unless ones knows exactly what one is doing.

Comment: ((The unsafe type casting is not part of the OCaml language per Xavier Leroy, and I agree with this way of looking at it.))

Comment: Yes, I understand it's claimed that it's not part of the language. I just said that it was possible to do it.